# How is the daughter of a "Graf" called?

Tags: noun

How is the daughter of a "Graf" called? The wife of a "Graf" is "Gräfin", but how would the daughter be called?
Most languages have a term for daughter, but due to my pitiful level of knowledge, I can't exactly dig through German sources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The German title of a *Graf* used to be (as opposed to, for example, the British *Earl*) directly inherited and did, in fact, **multiply**. That means, all sons of a *Graf* were automatically *Grafen* from the day they were born, all his daughters were *Gräfinnen*, at least until they got married.

In the 17th century, the habit to use the French word for *Gräfin* (Comptesse) for the daughters came up, the term ended up being germanised to *Komptess* or *Komptesse*.

Note this is only valid for the plain *Graf* title and not for Imperial functions like *Pfalzgraf*.

Note also that German traditionally used the title *Graf* outside nobility for special juristic and administrative functions, such as

- Freigraf (Judges)
- Deichgraf (Administrative function responsible for coastal protection)
- Salzgraf (main manager of salt works)

Those were obviously non-hereditary.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to tofros good answer, [this article from the Legal Tribune Online](https://www.lto.de/recht/hintergruende/h/namensrecht-nachname-titel-adel-akademischer-grad-namensaenderung/) might be informative.

Starting with the Weimar constitution of 1919, any privileges of nobility were abolished, and the former titles became simply parts of the name. So technically, the name of a [former Minister of Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl-Theodor_zu_Guttenberg) isn't "Herr zu Guttenberg" and he's a "Freiherr". His name (or a part thereof) is "Herr Freiherr zu Guttenberg".

As with names in general, children typically get their names from their parents. The daughter of "Herr und Frau Müller" is (in most cases) called "Müller", too. And the daughter of "Herr Freiherr zu Guttenberg" would technically be called "Frau Freiherr zu Guttenberg".

But there's an exception, according to the LTO article linked above. As early as 1926, there was [a court case](https://research.wolterskluwer-online.de/document/0d6212d9-b380-46dd-b81d-7c32d7c77c39) concerning the wife of a man named "Graf von Matuschka, Freiherr von Toppolczan und Spaetgen". The question was whether the deceased wife should be noted in the register of deaths as "Graf" and "Freiherr", or whether it should be allowed to use the female forms in the name. The judges in 1926 opted for the latter. Since then, it's acknowledged to use the gender-specific forms of the last name, in the case of marriage as well as for any offspring.

So, if the father's last name is "Graf von ...", the daughter's last name is "Gräfin von ...". But as noted above, this doesn't mean that the father would be a "Graf", or that the daughter would be a "Gräfin", those former titles are just part of their names.

Comment: This stack concerns all German languages and translations into German. Saying that a Graf isn't a Graf isn't a Graf is overspecific and wrong or underspecific and, as you said it yourself, meaningless.

Comment: just a fun aside, complicating your analysis even more: zu Guttenberg's name actually is [Buhl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl-Theodor_zu_Guttenberg), something he managed to hide before doing his second attempt at a PhD. Doing it in England seems to have meant more scrutiny of his nobility.